# How to manage maven dependant artifacts after creating release versions

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-release-plugin

We are using release plugin to convert snapshots to releases, but snapshots were already added as dependencies in other projects. Do we need to update every project pom, to use the new releases.

Eg: ArtifactA is included in ArtifactB,

ArtifactA is included in ArtifactC

ArtifactB and ArtifactC is included in Artifact D

Is there an alternate way to push dependent releases in place of snapshots

[We use Jenkins to build and push to Nexus]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our build server runs `versions:use-releases` followed by a commit to the SVN before the build. This replaces all SNAPSHOT versions by their respective release versions if they exist.

Comment: May be this is a good answer, but I do not know build server setup. Our  model: create feature branch and make changes, use jenkins job to buildanddeploy [ no nexus push]. Test the feature. If all ok, merge branch, which triggers build job, with deploy goal. This creates artifact in Nexus. obviously this is a snapshot. Now we created a new jenkins job with release goal to convert that project, This means I have to create 'n' jobs for my n projects. Is there an alternate/easy solution?

Comment: if you run scripted or declarative pipelines in Jenkins, you can define the different steps in there, including a step for each maven goal that you want to call.

Comment: Thanks.mvn versions:use-releases. I found this link https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/examples/use-releases.html

Answer (score -1):

A less cumbersome way of dealing with releases - keep using snapshots. Technically there's nothing wrong with snapshots and there's no need to change them to release versions. Just don't use versions with `SNAPSHOT` suffix - use resolved snapshots (with timestamp and build number).

As for the dependencies - usually there's no big need to change the version immediately after the release. It's only when clients *need* the updates - then they should change to newer versions manually.

If we're talking about remote API and its client lib as a dependency - such remote API needs to keep backward compatibility to give some time for others to upgrade.